# How to call custom server side function with mongodb nodejs driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I add a function to `system.js` that returns if number is odd or not and could not call it with aggregate function of nodejs driver. How can I call it?

Answer (score 1):

**To call a custom function**:

You can use [db.eval()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#eval). For example:

```
db.eval("echo(5)", function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(5, result);
});
```

But note that, as the documentation suggests, defining and calling a system level javascript function NOT recommended.

**To use a function in an aggregation**:

Basically, external/custom functions don't work with the aggregation framework. Everything is parsed to BSON on input, so no JavaScript or anything else is allowed.

Have a look at [Call function inside mongodb's aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865788/call-function-inside-mongodbs-aggregate) to find a workaround.

Comment: I think that function should be able to be used with queries. Could you give an example with aggregate function?