# Time difference on dates in $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to calculate with some dates in my aggregation and `$lookup`. I was first thinking of using a function within the aggregation, but JavaScript is not allowed to be used.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "sales",
    let: { user: "$_id" },
    pipeline: [
      $project: {
        time: //// CALCULATE TIME DIFFERENCE BETWEEN $createdAt and $startedAt,
      }
    ]
    as: "sales"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to return something similar to this in my `$project`?

```
const calculate = (created, started) => {
    const result = moment(created).diff(moment(started))
    return result
}
```

Comment: Seems that you cant call external functions inside aggregation pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/a/25866626/5373869

Comment: @DorukGüneş Thanks for clearing that up! Do you know how I could do a calculation with moment in the BSON aggregation?

Comment: @oniramarf Edited my question, as it is different.

Comment: I think they're very similar, you have just to use different pipeline operators from the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the possible duplicate of another question, you should use one of the [aggregation pipeline operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). In particular, you should use [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator, that works also with dates.

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "sales",
    let: { user: "$_id" },
    pipeline: [
      $project: {
        time: { $subtract: ["$createdAt", "$startedAt"]}
      }
    ]
    as: "sales"
  }
}
```