# Vanilla function call within mongodb aggregator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an aggregator setup and need to run a vanilla JS function call to manipulate the data prior to using the $out stage.

Here's what I have so far:

```
myFunc = (x) => {
    newObj = {
        prop_id: x.prop_id,
        newValue: x.file_as_name
    }
    return newObj;
}

(async () => {

    const dbURL = `mongodb://localhost:27017`
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })


    let agg = [
        { $match: {} },
        { $limit: 5 },
        {
            '$replaceRoot': {
                'newRoot': {
                    '_id': '$$ROOT._id',
                    'prop_id': myFunc('$$ROOT')
                }
            }
        },


        { $out: 'test' }
    ]


    try {
        let rex = await client.db('mydb').collection('mycollection').aggregate(agg)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }


})()
```

The documents right now end up with:

```
{
  "_id": "5ed80b8311ad182ed7594d3d",
  "newObj": {
    "prop_id": null,
    "newValue": null
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that `myFunc` is able to access the data contained with `$$ROOT` that gets passed to it?

Comment: Check the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865788/call-function-inside-mongodbs-aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier there is [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) operator to execute a JavaScript function in MongoDB query language, but usually it's discouraged to use it cause executing .Js functions can highly impact performance & [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator from version `3.6` has replaced most chances of using `$where`.

**From documentation :**

> The use of JavaScript with scope for the $where function has been
>   deprecated since version 4.2.1.

Starting MongoDB version `4.4` you'll a new operator [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) to define custom aggregation functions or JavaScript expressions.

For now, I believe you don't need to use any of these operators for your scenario :

```
let agg = [
  { $match: {} },
  { $limit: 5 },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        _id: "$$ROOT._id",
        prop_id: {
            prop_id: "$$ROOT.prop_id",
            newValue: "$$ROOT.file_as_name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "test" }
];
```